# How to take up center space between to divs?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 3 `div`s inside a div wrapper.

**Div 1** is set to `float:left`, **Div 3** to `float:right`.

How can I force **Div 2** to take up all the space left, be centered and that all 3 are still in one row?

If i try `margin: 0 auto;` or `overflow: hidden;` **Div 3** doesn't stay in the same row.

```
.div_wrapper {

    width: 600px;
}

.div_1{ 
    float: left;
}
.div_2 {        
    margin: 0 auto; NOT WORKING
    overflow: hidden; NOT WORKING
}
.div_3 {
    width: 60px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: You should use `display:flex` and `flex-flow: row wrap;`. Take a look here: http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/qIAwr

Comment: Like I said in my answer... the order of the divs are very important in this scenario. You must have them in the code as div_1, div_3, div_2. Your floats should always be before your non-float.

Comment: well, I still don't understand it. if possible, give the result on image pls

Answer (score 0):

If you float all three to the left and set their widths to 33.33333%.

Comment: Yeah, but i want the left Box to automaticly take the width of its content and the right one needs to be fixed 60px.

Comment: If you know the width of the div's then just simply set them.

Comment: how about  `width: calc(100% - 60px);` ?

Comment: That's not what the OP asked for. Not to make all 3 columns equal, but to make the left and right float with a center court that is variable only.

Comment: It was originally. It has been edited since. Hence why I had an up vote on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to your problem is with the order of your `<div>` elements, and setting `overflow:auto` on the parent. The `<div>` is a block-level element by default, so you don't need to do anything special for it to try to use all available width.

Notice the order of the children: 1, 3, 2

```
<style>
.div_wrapper {width: 600px; overflow:auto;}

.div_1 {width:60px; float:left;}
.div_2 {}
.div_3 {width:60px; float:right;}
</style>

<div class="div_wrapper">
    <div class="div_1">Morbi mollis iaculis egestas. Nullam quis nisi at lorem laoreet congue non sollicitudin ante.</div>
    <div class="div_3">Pellentesque sodales, justo eget iaculis egestas, nulla lectus consectetur est, pharetra rhoncus purus tortor vel mauris. </div>
    <div class="div_2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent id justo quis purus suscipit finibus nec eu augue. Suspendisse sollicitudin rhoncus risus, sit amet consequat velit suscipit non. Vivamus faucibus faucibus nisl eu gravida. Etiam id ipsum non lorem semper tincidunt. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque massa orci, venenatis at purus sed, maximus ullamcorper sem. Cras non sollicitudin quam, ut iaculis felis. Donec rhoncus nisi quis sapien imperdiet tincidunt nec et massa. Mauris felis leo, viverra in consectetur quis, malesuada non neque. Cras at magna massa. Cras non tellus vel ex euismod blandit et non dolor. Nullam at ex nisi. Integer feugiat congue euismod. Quisque consequat urna eget ligula finibus pellentesque.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the downvotes?! This totally works in all browsers.

Comment: I also don't understand the downvotes - because it does work but only if you add a width to div_1 which the OP didn't added to his example. So +1 for working code. also width:50% should work here to take the second div the space it should get.

Comment: You're right. I added the width because his question didn't match the code. In this question is sounded like only the center court is variable.

Comment: Also if we are adding `width:50%` it will do the trick - maybe my answer is a little bit more easy to understand. anyway: there shouldn't be a downvote for a working example.

Comment: I see this okay too. what motives for dv?

Comment: Strangely the only wrong answer got an upvote ;) crazy world.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use another `wrapper` inside the first `wrapper` with the max width of `540px`, if `600px` is the max width which is also floated to the left. And inside the `inner_wrapper` it you can simply assign them again a % width.

HTML:

```
<div class="div_wrapper">
    <div class="div_inner_wrapper">
        <div class="div_1_2 div_1"></div>
        <div class="div_1_2 div_2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div_1_2_3 div_3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div_wrapper {
    width: 600px;
}

.div_inner_wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 540px;
}
.div_1_2 { 
    float: left;
    width:50%;
}
.div_1 {
    height: 30px; // only here for displaying the div
    background-color: green; // only here for displaying the div
}
.div_2 {
    height: 30px; // only here for displaying the div
    background-color: yellow; // only here for displaying the div
}
.div_3 {
    float:left;
    width:60px;
    height: 30px; // only here for displaying the div
    background-color: red; // only here for displaying the div
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DominikAngerer/5167my47/1/)

Comment: Why add additional code, when it's perfectly easy to do this without nested wrappers.

Comment: See my comment to your answer @theVinchi